# Retrofit APIService Injection by Dagger Hilt in MVP Architecture's Model Class

Tags: android, retrofit2, mvp, dagger-hilt

I am trying to inject retrofit `APIServices` dependency into the model class. Here is My API Module Source Code:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApiModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesHttpLoggingInterceptor() = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesOkHttpClient(httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient =
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        .build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit =
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(ApiConfig.BASE_URL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("ApiService")
fun providesApiService(retrofit: Retrofit):ApiServices =
    retrofit.create(ApiServices::class.java)
}
```

For User Registration, I am using MVP Architecture Pattern where `FragmentRegistration.kt` is `view` layer, `RegistrationModel` is `model` layer class

When I inject `ApiServices` dependency into `FragmentRegistration`, it works fine. But when I try to inject it into model layer class, which is `RegistrationModel`, It doesn't work.

***RegistrationModel:***

```
class RegistrationModel(
    val presenter: RegistrationContract.Presenter
    ) : RegistrationContract.Model {

    @Inject
    @Named("ApiService")
    lateinit var apiServices: ApiServices

    override fun onDataReady(registrationData: RegistrationData) {
        val map = mapOf(
            "Accept" to "application/json",
            "Content-Type" to "application/json"
        )

        apiServices.userRegistration(map, registrationData)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<RegistrationResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<RegistrationResponse>,
                    response: Response<RegistrationResponse>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataReady: ${response.body().toString()}")

                    } else {
                        val apiFailure = APIFailure(
                            response.code(),
                            response.message()
                        )
                        presenter.onSignupFailure(apiFailure)
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataReady: Error ${response.code()}")
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataReady: Error Body ${response.errorBody()}")
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<RegistrationResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    presenter.onSignupFailure(
                        APIFailure(-1, t.toString())
                    )
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: $t")
                }
            })
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "RegistrationModel"
    }
}
```

In the above's Code,

```
 @Inject
 @Named("ApiService")
 lateinit var apiServices: ApiServices
```

this dependency injection is not working.

Comment: Could you provide the error you are getting ?

Comment: @SergioPardo it shows lateinit var apiServices: ApiServices is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject a filed provided by Hilt into a class which is not managed by Hilt. This will not work out of the box. You have to define EntryPoint for you custom class, so the Hilt can perform injection. You can read how to do that here: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported